# Soundcloud soundwave

Tags: php, wav, soundcloud, waveform

I am trying to generate soundwave which would look like the one that soundcloud have.

But i can't figure out how do they make their soundwaves so clear, for example this is an example of soundcloud and my generated soundwave:

[image]

I am using to php to read wav file and generate the image, but if there is some better library in any language which would do this better i would definitely like to to hear about it.

I have pasted the class that I'm usin in [**Pastebin**](http://pastebin.com/LFKW2XKg).

I got this code from [**andrewfreiday.com**](http://andrewfreiday.com/2010/04/29/generating-mp3-waveforms-with-php/) and modified to fit my website.

I'm really lost at this and any kind of suggestion would help a lot.

Comment: Have you already tried changing the `$detail` property in the class?

Comment: @Gargron yes i did, it does increase quality  a little but far from what I'm expecting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The waveforms on soundcloud.com are drawn with canvas -- whereas in your sample image, it appears as though it's a larger image which is scaled down to the desired size. When you do this scaling in the browser, it will anti-alias the 'half' pixels. When drawing to the canvas, we draw exactly the pixels needed at the exact resolution needed. This means there's no image scaling and no blurriness.

Answer (score 0):

the tool you are looking for is located at https://www.un4seen.com/

soundcloud uses some simple tactics.

say soundwave will be 595 pixels wide.. each bar will be 5 pixels + 2 pixels blank.

595 / ( 5 + 2 ) = 85
length / (bar + space ) = 85 total (bars with space)

device song into 85 parts
lets say song is 3:00 long.. 
3*60 = 180/85 = 2 seconds
minute * seconds = total seconds / parts = 2 seconds / bar
so, now we get the peak of a song every 2 seconds.

save max peak.
save low peak.

now you have a list of 85 bars with exact highest peak and lowest peak to display them accordingly with song relative to time.

use positive numbers to display upper portion.
divide by 2 OR 3 OR 4 and use negative numbers to display lower portion.
combine the two and use it as a filter to draw the colors of the graph.
kaboom!